# Estoy creando una función para crear servidores pero no funciona y no sé por qué

Tags: javascript, nodejs, json, typescript

Estoy intentando crear la función para que cree un servidor de forma semi automática pero siempre crashea y no tengo ni idea del porqué.

```
    const express = require("express");
    const path = require("path");

    function crearServidor(a, b, c = "localhost"){
      try{
        console.clear();
        const servidor = express();
        const port = b;

        servidor.get("/",(req,res)=>{
          const pathFile = path.join(__dirname + `/${a}`);
          res.sendFile(pathFile);
        });

        servidor.use(express.static(__dirname));

        servidor.listen(port,()=>{
          console.log(`El servidor está funcionando en http://${c}:${port}`);
        });
      }catch(error){
        console.error(erro.message);
      };
    };

    export {
    crearServidor
    }
```

Archivo JSON

```json
    {
      "name": "javascript-practica",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon servidor.js"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.18.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^3.0.2"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Parece que puedes deshacerte de `console.clear()`, no funciona en todos los entornos y se usa mas para la etapa de desarrollo

Comment: ¿Cómo *crashea* (falla)? Algún mensaje de error? Cuál? Haz clic en [edit] y agrega esa información a tu pregunta.

Comment: Deberías de enfocarte en los mensaje de error, así pueda que determines si el problema es generado por la forma de ejecutar comando `script`

Comment: Determina que cada método funcione de manera correcta

Comment: Me dice que falla en __dirname y en la dirección

Comment: También en la importación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas mezclando la sintaxis de importación/exportación [CommonJS Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) con [ESModules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html). Si no tienes definida la propiedad `"type"` en tu *package.json*, su valor sera por defecto "CommonJS". Puedes exportar tu función para crear servidores así:

```
module.exports = {
  crearServidor,
};
```

Si vas a exportar una función lo normal es que no la uses allí mismo, importa dicha función en el archivo index.js (que por convención suele ser el entry point de la aplicación) y llama a la función:

```
const { crearServidor } = require('./servidor')

crearServidor('myfile.txt', 3000)
```

Modificas el script `"start"` para que nodemon observe los cambios en index.js:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "nodemon index.js"
 },
```

El servidor debería estar corriendo y si vas a *https:localhost:3000* deberías ver el contenido de *myfile.txt*.
Por el contrario si vas a user ESModules la cosa cambia un poco, además __dirname ya no funcionaria en ese caso, te lo dejo para que lo investigues